# iOS 2D Game Development

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

I have basically zero knowledge on the game development. I have looked into cocos2d a bit, and followed through some basic Unity3d tutorials.

I want to create a character based game(walking on a road, jumping above obstacles) which is going to be controlled by gyroscope. I don't care about cross-platforms, not at the moment at least. Looks like Unity is a bit confusing considered I am going to create a basic 2d game.

What is the basic concepts? Which should be the most convenient and easy-to-implement engine to build 2d games for iOS (preferably free),  for my kind of game?

I stand confused and I am trying to look into all engines and since I have zero knowledge I am lost. I consider myself as a above-novice iOS developer (5 Apps on AppStore), but game development is a whole different concept and I don't want to spend days trying to find the best tutorials and the most suitable engine for my situation.

Comment: Read the tutorials on [Ray's website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

Comment: Your question is way general and an answer could take a considerable amount of pages. @ekims link is a very good way to start from

Comment: not really a programming question, try asking it on gamedev: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocos2d is an excellent engine for both 2d and 3d. Ray wanderlich has collection of good tut's for starters. Tim roadley also has a good set of tut's on box2d which is related to cocos2d. Also there is a wiki site for it. Cocos2d has a web site as well that walkers you through everything. There is also game salad that has some people raving about it too. There are two or so more free engines out there. It all depends to how much time and energy you want to invest in this. If you search on the web you can find those guys sites. As I said all the materials are free, it just requires time.

Comment: I have no problem with spending time, actually I got the job so it is a must, but I am not sure where should I look for. Just need some confirmation and I want to confirm that these engines, especially cocos2d, covers all basegrounds. I have a 2 month deadline, not sure I can go through it

Comment: I made my first game which I sold the entire project to a game company for a lump sum in about 3 weeks. That being said I have a day job. It really depends to what the game is and how much coding it requires. Cocos2d is by far the easiest I came a cross. In your situation, definitely not unity. Go for cocos2d it is free and very much compatible with iOS. Try ray's tuts if you like. But his stuff are always incomplete. You have to check what you want to put in your game and all the stuff you need are freely available. Good luck my friend

Comment: can you meet me at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17847/cocos2d

Comment: Sure. I have sometime. I'll be there right away.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a few grand, or are a student/school faculty you can get Unity3D for a discounted rate. Unity3D is a powerful, easy, and comprehensive 2D/3D game engine/platform for iOS/Android, Windows, MAC, and many others.

The learning curve is small, and the whole ideal of develop once and publish everywhere is prominent. www.unity3d.com.

Comment: I see that there is a Free version of unity, which comes with an $400 iOS pack, on the other hand, Pro version ($1500) and iOS Pro Pack ($1500). Should I go with the Free Unity + iOS Pack (total $400) ?

Answer (score 0):

This [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial) will get you started with [Cocos2d](http://www.Cocos2d-iPhone.com) which is an excellent 2D engine for beginners coming to the iPhone.